# Dynamic Routes loading throwing error "No Factory found"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

Hi I am trying to load routes dynamically returned by API server. I am calling a http service in app.component to get routing data.
But I get error "No Component factory found for component".I have my components added in entryComponent here is my code.

error:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ParentComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for ParentComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.es5.js:3202)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.es5.js:3267)
    at RouterOutlet.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.es5.js:5614)
    at ActivateRoutes.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.es5.js:4749)
    at router.es5.js:4700

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routingComponents,AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

import { RouterService } from './router.service';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
routingComponents
 ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,HttpModule
],
providers: [RouterService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
entryComponents:[ParentComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

const routes: Routes = []

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
export const routingComponents = 
[ParentComponent]
```

router.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from 
'@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RouterService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

 getRoutes(){
    return this.http.get("assets/json/router.json")
    .map((response:Response)=>{
        const extracted = response.json();
        console.log("router service",extracted);
        return extracted;
    })
}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterService } from './router.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private router: Router, private routerService: RouterService) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
this.routerService.getRoutes().subscribe(response => {
  this.router.resetConfig(response);
})
}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem now. Did you find a solution?